# Indexing a string in python

Tags: python, pandas

Row is equal to the below. PIC_loc = 23; I want 42 and the 15 digits after 42. Output should be 42011721930018984

```
                                            PIC_1  p_lgth  Wgt
**PARTIAL-DECODE***P / 42011721930018984390078...      53  112

Output = row['PIC_1'][PIC_loc:PIC_loc+15]
```

Code above gives this error message

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on    
class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [2    23
Name: PIC_1, dtype: int64] of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: PIC_1 is a string; it's the entire line that starts with "**PARTIAL" and ends with "0078..."

Comment: When you asked this yesterday Joran Beasley gave you a solution to try in a comment, namely `fifteencharactersfollowing42 = a_string.split("42",1)[-1][:15]`.  Did that not work?  If `PIC_1` is a string as you describe it works fine for me.

Comment: Gives message "KeyError: -1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row['PIC_1']` returns a Pandas series so you need to access the values before you can slice them. You're looking to slice a string so you can use `pandas.Series.str` vectorised string methods:

```
row['PIC_1'].str[PIC_loc:PIC_loc+15]
```

Comment: Tried this and got NAN for the output value

Comment: What does `row['PIC_1']` return?

Comment: `row['PIC_1']`
 
`**PARTIAL-DECODE***P / 42011721930018984390078...`
                                                                                                                `Name: PIC_1, dtype: object`

Comment: Not sure why that's not working. I'm recreating your data as `pd.Series(['**PARTIAL-DECODE***P / 42011721930018984390078']).str[23:23+17]` which works fine.

Comment: Thanks for trying

Comment: If I replace PIC_loc with numbers, the code works.  `row['PIC_1'].str[23:28]` works

Comment: `row['PIC_1'].str[int(PIC_loc):int(PIC_loc+15)]` got the job done

Comment: Ahh you had PIC_loc stored as a string i.e. `PIC_loc = '23'` rather than `PIC_loc = 23`. Glad you got it working.